# nginx can not access another ext4 partition on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, file-permissions

I have ubuntu 16.04 installed, root(/) partition as ext4. I created another ext4 filesystem from unallocated space and it works normally when i create files, folders etc.

The problem is, when i changed my directory path in my nginx conf to the new partition, it throws 404 on the browser and nginx log says "Permission Denied". I checked all permissions, user and groups, everything is okay and all of them are same as the *already working* directory in my root partition.

Here is my mount list (only relevants shown):

- `/dev/sda9 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)`
- `/dev/sda11 on /media/me/dev type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)`

Nginx error log says:

`2017/08/27 22:58:47 [crit] 13607#13607: *1 stat() "/media/me/dev/www/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: ::1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"`

Nginx uses `www-data` user, and still doesn't work if i change all files in the new partition to be owned by `www-data` or make them chmod 777.

I tried various solutions which didn't work so far. Any idea ?

EDIT:

- ps aux | grep nginx:

  `root      1790  0.0  0.0  33560  2300 ?        Ss   08:20   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
  www-data  1791  0.0  0.0  33560  3292 ?        S    08:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
  www-data  1792  0.0  0.0  33560  3292 ?        S    08:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
  www-data  1793  0.0  0.0  33560  3292 ?        S    08:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
  www-data  1794  0.0  0.0  33560  3292 ?        S    08:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
  www-data  1795  0.0  0.0  33560  3292 ?        S    08:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
  www-data  1796  0.0  0.0  33560  3292 ?        S    08:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
  www-data  1797  0.0  0.0  33560  3292 ?        S    08:20   0:00 nginx: worker process
  www-data  1798  0.0  0.0  33560  3292 ?        S    08:20   0:00 nginx: worker process`
- ls -la /media

  `drwxr-xr-x   3 root      root      4096 apr 10  2016 .
  drwxr-xr-x  27 root      root      4096 avg 16 10:11 ..
  drwxr-x---+  7 me        me        4096 avg 28 08:34 me
  lrwxrwxrwx   1 root      root        45 apr 10  2016 .directory -> /etc/kubuntu-default-settings/directory-media
  lrwxrwxrwx   1 root      root        42 apr 10  2016 .hidden -> /etc/kubuntu-default-settings/hidden-media`
- ls -la /media/me

  `drwxr-x---+ 7 me        me  4096 avg 28 08:34 .
  drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root  4096 apr 10  2016 ..
  drwxr-xr-x  5 me        me  4096 avg 28 09:47 dev`
- ls -la /media/me/dev

  `drwxr-xr-x  5 me me  4096 avg 27 23:14 .
  drwxr-x---+ 6 me me  4096 avg 28 08:28 ..
  drwx------  2 me me 16384 avg 27 22:54 lost+found
  drwxrwxrwx  2 me me  4096 avg 27 23:24 www`
- ls -la /media/me/dev/www

  `drwxrwxrwx 2 me me 4096 avg 28 08:31 ./
  drwxr-xr-x 5 me me 4096 avg 27 23:14 ../
  rwxrwxrwx 1 me me   22 avg 28 08:31 index.php*`

Comment: Add output of `ps aux | grep nginx` to your question. Also add output of `ls -al /media/`, `ls -al /media/me`, `ls -al /media/me/dev/`

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites, either http://askubuntu.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com  (Unix & Linux).  Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I added the information to the post.

Comment: The info still doesn't have all the info i asked. Two other `ls` results missing

Comment: @TarunLalwani Sorry my mistake. I added the others now

Comment: Try this `chmod a+x /media; chmod a+x /media/me;` This should fix the issue

Comment: Nope. It didnt change anything :/ Same permission denied error logged.

Comment: This seems to be very odd. By any chance your OS has SELinux or some other protection enabled. Because of that is what is left to check

Comment: Indeed very odd. Selinux is disabled i already checked that multiple times. Might be another thing i dont know.